# Links working on server but not remotely

Tags: error, site, site-settings

so I am working for a client and they are experiencing the following problem: some of the links and functions on their site such as uploading documents, site settings, site contents and etc. are working when I access the website from their server but if I try to do it from my computer I get either:

> "Error: List does not exist"
>
> or "Error: File not found"

Do you have any idea what might be the reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly sounds like a DNS problem to me.

Have you checked your alternate access mapping configuration?